# LINQ unable to translate query after update to EF Core 6/7

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, npgsql

I have recently updated a project to .NET 6 with EF Core 7 and NPGSQL 7 from .NET 5.

I have added the following to my startup:

```cs
AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
```

Most of my queries are running ok, but I am having issues with it translating a few date queries.

An example of a query that is no longer functioning is:

```cs
var roomlistlatest1 = _context.roomlistlatest
                              .Where(c => c.statusdate.Value.Date == DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).Date);
```

I get the following error:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet() .Where(r => r.statusdate.Value.Date == DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).Date)' could not be translated.

`_context.roomlistlatest` is a view that has a model and `statusdate` is a timestamp that has been set in the model to a nullable `DateTime`.

The reason I am using `.Date` is that I need to get the date without the time for this specific query.

Has anybody come across this after upgrading a project, and if so, any ideas on how I can get passed this?

I have many queries that use similar behaviour so need a generic work around if there is one.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Have you tried extracting the value of `DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).Date` into a variable and passing that in instead?

Comment: I have just found that `DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)` instead of `DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).Date` seems to work so am just doing some more testing.

Comment: `DateTime.Today` already has no time part (or more precise, its time part is zero) so not using `.Date` should be OK. @DavidG note that EF will translate `DateTime.Today` in a server-side call the the database's function to get the current date. That may cause differences due to time zones or clock differences.

Comment: Instead of including `DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).Date` in the query itself, calculate it in advance. This is a constant, it doesn't have to get calculated in the database. Besides, `DateTime.Today` has no time element. There's no reason to add another `.Date` call.

Comment: Could you specify which version of EF Core you are upgrading from. It is clear that you updated .NET 5 -> .NET 6. However, it is not clear which version of EF Core you are coming from: EF Core (6?) -> EF Core 7.

Comment: This document specifies breaking changes in EF Core 7. It also links to breaking changes in older versions of EF Core, depending on which version you are upgrading from.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes